# How to take value from Object in ArrayList displayed in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-toast

I got short question. I got `ListView` that displays my objects from  `ArrayList`. I want to have `Toast` that can display one of the values from my Object when I click on the item on a list (for instance when my object is called `Product` i want to have displayed the name of this product). My code looks like this below and I don't know where to put `getProductName()` or something.

```
 final ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Product p: md.takeAllProducts()){

        productList.add(p);
    }

    ProductListAdapter adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this,R.layout.adapter_view_layout,productList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(ProductsList.this, mListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameters passed to `onItemClick()` to accomplish this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Product p = (Product) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), p.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Of course, you can replace `p.toString()` with whatever methods you have available in the `Product` class, like `p.getName()` etc.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot :) I've spent so much time trying to solve this... :D

Comment: You're very welcome. If you think this helped you, please consider accepting and/or upvoting so that other people can see that it helped. Comments can be deleted at any time.